# How can I get data of selected table rows?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following snippet and from this I can find the index of a row which one is selected on the basis of checkbox on every row of the table.How can I modify this snippet so that I can get the selected row data instead of index?
Please Help!!

```
<script>

function myfunction3() {
  var element_table = document.getElementsByName('collection');
  var element_tableRows = element_table[0].rows;
  var selectedTr = new Array();
  var data = "";

  for (var i = 0; i < element_tableRows.length; i++) {
    var checkerbox = element_tableRows[i].cells[0].firstChild;
    if (checkerbox.checked) {
      data = data+ element_tableRows[i].getAttribute("name");
    }
  }

  var element_paragraph = document.getElementsByName('description');
  element_paragraph.innerHTML = data;
  alert(data);
}

</script>
```

Comment: please post your 'collection' code

Comment: i don't see any code where you're getting `index`.

Comment: 'collection' is the name of the table.
I am getting the index as an alert!

Comment: In the name attribute I've kept an 'count' variable through that i'm getting the index.
Should I give the rest of the code?

Answer (score 0):

as TJ says, i dont see any index in your code. but try something like this which is cleaner

```
$('.collection tr').each(function () {
    //processing this row
    $(this).find('td input:checked').each(function () {
         // there is checkbox and it is checked, do your business with it
         var value_of_checkbox = $(this).val(); // which is 'data' that you wanted
    });
});
```

Comment: @ShaswatiSaha just try the code. i already understood your problem

Comment: Please don't mind.I can't understand where to add your code in my code

Comment: I understand my plan. 
Is this right? see, i've changed my script 
http://paste.ubuntu.com/8194686/